# Google Infowindow image not showing if src protocol is https

Tags: android, jquery, google-maps, browser

I am not so familiar with google maps API, tried to search for this, without success.

I have a page, where I have a `google map`, and a `marker` on it. If you click on it, the `infowindow` appears.

I have an API server, what is running on `https` only. The information for the `infowindow` is coming from here, as the image too.

If the source of the image is on https, then **under android** (Chrome, FF), the image is not appears.

Funny thing is, that on desktop, it works in both cases.

If I am changing the source of the image, then it works.

You can check it:

http version: http://ytic.hu/test/

https version: http://ytic.hu/test/?a=a

In the first case, the image is: http://ytic.hu/DSC_0042.JPG and you will see red border around the image.

In the second case the image is: https://service.contactless.hu/media/partners/000031/DSC_0042.JPG and there is a green border (but picture doesn't shows)

Of course, I thought, maybe the problem is, that in the second case, the domain is not the same. I tried with a picture, what is on another domain without `https` and that worked.

Can anybody explain me, what happens here?

**UPDATE:**
I've reported this issue as a bug, and I've got answer to it:

> Thanks for this.
>
> When I look at the console, it says net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
>
> And when I open the image in a new tab (in Chrome Android) it says that the image's certificate is not trusted by my device's operating system. So probably the problem is that the certificate is not trusted by the Android OS, whereas it is trusted on other OSes.
>
> Doesn't look like a bug in the Maps API.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7832&thanks=7832&ts=1427788008

Comment: reported as a bug: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7832&thanks=7832&ts=1427788008 I am alone here with this.

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be that Android Java Script is not enabled please follow the below

Android

Follow these instructions to activate and enable JavaScript on your Android.

- Select **Browser or Internet** to open the web browser.
- Select **Menu**.
- Select **More** then **Settings**.
- Finally select **Enable JavaScript**.

Comment: Of course, the problem is not that. Map appears, marker appears, in non SLL version is working, so javascript enabled. Delete this answer before the downvotes.